# How to create directory from script path

Tags: python, python-3.9

When I run this code:

```
script_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
new_abs_path = os.path.join(script_path, 'Users')
if not os.path.exists(new_abs_path):
    os.makedirs(new_abs_path)
```

I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified '<script drive>\\<script path>\\<script filename>\\User'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use Python 3.9, you can use [Path.mkdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir):

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(__file__).parent / 'Users'
path.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
```

I strongly advise you to use pathlib.Path, it provide very useful tools to manipulate path, files and directories.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import os
os.makedirs(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Users'), exist_ok=True)
```

You forget to take the directory of your python script. You can t create a folder inside a file...